# Perform script before permanent redirect based on cookie?

Tags: php, redirect, cookies

I'm currently upgrading our webapp to use subdomains. Previously we hosted everything on `www.mywebsite.com` but now it would be something like `app.mywebsite.com`.

To do this transition without breaking anything I would need to run a script before doing the permanent redirect. This due to the fact that the working is based on a cookie which I would use in the redirect. For example the redirect url would be `app.mywebsite.com/upgrade?cookievalue`. If the cookie is not present I would simply need to redirect them to `app.mywebsite.com`

**Question**

Is it a bad idea to run a script before doing the permanent redirect?

Comment: Not in general, no. But trying to set a cookie and redirect at the same time can sometimes be problematic in some browsers ...

Comment: I would not be setting a cookie but rather reading a value from one that is already been set on `www.mywebsite.com`. Using this cookie's value to determine the redirect URL

Comment: Well that should be no problem at all.

Comment: @CBroe ok thanks :)